# Rectangle animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, storyboard

I am trying to translate a rectangle on the Y access using a DataTrigger.
It works great except I want the rectangle to move from its current transformed state instead of restarting from the initialstate.
I would like an all XAML solution.
I have tried setting the Completed property but WPF won't allow that.
Thanks in advance.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentFloor}" Value="5">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="sb5">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation 
                    To="5" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Y"
                    Duration="0:0:2"
                />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb5" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentFloor}" Value="4">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="sb4">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation 
                    To="75" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Y"
                    Duration="0:0:2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="sb4" />
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Just add the From property for the storyboard

Comment: I do not know the From property value.  It is whatever the current transformation position is.

Comment: If you have the rectangle in a canvas, then you can bind the canvas top or left property to the From property.

Comment: being extremely new to wpf.  I will take a look at the canvas and see if I can work this out. Seems like it is already bound this way to my DockPanel though.

Comment: use StopStoryboard, not RemoveStoryboard.

Comment: putting in stopstoryboard has the exact same animation effect.

Comment: Ok, well do you mean <DoubleAnimation By="5"/>  not To="5" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<DoubleAnimation By="5" .../>` not `<DoubleAnimation To="5" .../>`